# Possible to boot Mac Pro from two PCIe M.2 AHCI PCIe SSD in RAID 0 on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, ssd

I have an M.2 AHCI PCIe SSD and I am considering purchasing a second one to install both in a 2009 Mac Pro in a RAID 0 configuration using Disk Utility similar to the setup in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeP98UTObaY).

I have used my current M.2 AHCI PCIe SSD in the past as a single bootable drive into macOS Sierra, but want to increase performance and storage by setting these up in a bootable RAID 0 config.

My primary concern is that macOS sees these SSDs as external, so I'm concerned that even though I can boot from one AHCI PCIe SSD there might be problems booting from two in a RAID 0 config, or I might not be able to create a RAID 0 config in Recovery tools at all.

Is what I want to do possible?